# Is number theory $K$ $\aleph_0$-categorical?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $K$ be the number theory. The language of $K$ contains the following symbols: $\{0, 1, +, \cdot, <, =\}$. Furthermore, the proper axioms are Peano axioms.

My question is, is $K$ $\aleph_0$-catergorical?

From what I learned, a theory with equality $K$ is $\aleph_0$-categorical if and only if

1. $K$ has at least one countably infinite normal model
2. Any two countably infinite normal models of $K$ are isomorphic.

I believe $K$ has at least one countably infinite normal model. We can just take the standard natural number model, right?

What's left is showing that (2) is true, assuming that $K$ is indeed $\aleph_0$-categorical. But we have to take two arbitrary countably infinite normal models (let's call them $M_1$ and $M_2$) of $K$ and show that they are isomorphic. There is not much information about $M_1$ and $M_2$ I believe, so I was wondering if there is a model $M$ of $K$ that has a denumerable normal model, but $M$ is not isomorphic to a standard natural number model (for example).
Any hints/explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but weirdly enough I can't seem to find an MSE question which simply asks "Why does PA have a countable nonstandard model?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not even close to $\aleph_0$-categorical.

First of all, per [Godel's incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#First_incompleteness_theorem) Peano arithmetic isn't even complete. Consequently, per [Godel's *completeness* theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) there are countable models which are not elementarily equivalent to the standard one, so a fortiori not isomorphic to it.

- Strictly speaking, the mere statement of the completeness theorem doesn't say that a countable model exists. However, we can get this by looking at the Henkinization proof of that theorem, which explicitly builds a countable model, or by applying downwards Lowenheim-Skolem (see below) after the fact.

---

What if we replace Peano arithmetic with the full theory $\mathsf{TA}$ (**t**rue **a**rithmetic) of the structure $(\mathbb{N}; 0,1,+,\cdot,<,=)$? Well, $\mathsf{TA}$ is by definition complete so the above doesn't work. However, via the [Lowenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) we can show that even $\mathsf{TA}$ is not $\aleph_0$-categorical.

Via the upwards part of the theorem *(which is really just a corollary of [compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem))*, let $\mathfrak{A}$ be an uncountable - hence a fortiori nonstandard - model of $\mathsf{TA}$. Now via the downwards part of the theorem *(this is the really interesting half of the theorem)*, fix some infinite element $a\in\mathfrak{A}$ and let $\mathfrak{B}$ be a countable elementary substructure of $\mathfrak{A}$ with $a\in \mathfrak{B}$. This $\mathfrak{B}$ is a countable nonstandard model of $\mathsf{TA}$.

Comment: Is $T$ a model of $\mathbb{N}$ that contains infinitely large natural numbers? If so, the domain of $T$ is uncountable isn't it?

Comment: @VicRyan Sorry, I left the countability argument implicit; I've edited to make things more explicit and simpler. As to your comment, first of all you're again conflating theories and structures, but more importantly a model of arithmetic with infinitely large natural numbers need *not* be uncountable.