# Number Theory K is $ℵ0$-categorical

Tags: logic, proof-writing, first-order-logic

Prove or disprove:

Number Theory K is $\aleph_0$-categorical

(domain of $K$ is $\mathbb{N}$, language contains {0, 1, +, ·, <, =},
proper axioms: Peano)

Is there a simple proof?
I already tried to find it on the forum.

But they did not proof it on: [Is number theory $K$ $\aleph_0$-categorical?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3892837/is-number-theory-k-aleph-0-categorical)

Comment: The post you linked to gives a disproof.

Comment: This may be reopened if you explain why the disproof(s) at the linked question (via Godel + Lowenheim-Skolem, or just via Lowenheim-Skolem) do not satisfy you.